# Implications of changing compatibility mode in SQL Server from 100 to 110

Tags: sql-server-2012, compatibility-level

I have a database `Mydatabase` created in SQL Server 2008 R2. I have upgraded to SQL Server 2012.

I was trying to execute below query to calculate percentile

```
select Distinct [KEY],PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25)  within group(order by EachPrice)
OVER(Partition By [KEY]) As Q1,PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50)  within group(order by EachPrice)
OVER(Partition By [KEY]) As Q2,
PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75)  within group(order by EachPrice)
OVER(Partition By [KEY]) As Q3,
PERCENTILE_CONT(1)  within group(order by EachPrice)
OVER(Partition By [KEY]) As Q4
from Mydatabase
```

but I am getting an error stating that

> Msg 10762, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   The PERCENTILE_CONT function is not allowed in the current compatibility mode. It is only allowed in 110 mode or higher.

1. Can I change compatibility mode to 110?
2. What are the implications of changing compatibility mode from 100 to 110?

Please advice

Comment: OMFG! "SQL Server 2014 includes substantial improvements to the component that creates and optimized query plans." But` I haven't been benefiting from that at all for the past 3 years because my `compatibility_level` is still at 100. Fantastic!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the following link:

[ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)

Scroll down and you will see the section "Differences Between Lower Compatibility Levels and Level 110" and identify if any of these items will affect you or not.  If not, then just change the level to 110.

Comment: That would take hours. There is a tool that does this for you, now: Microsoft [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595)

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) helps you quickly and easily find any issues that may prevent or complicate an upgrade.

If it finds no issues (or if it does, and you've addressed them) you can simply upgrade by running these commands, one at a time:

```
USE master
go
ALTER DATABASE [yourdatabasesname]  SET SINGLE_USER     WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
go
ALTER DATABASE [yourdatabasesname]  SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 110    -- 130=SQL Server 2016, 120=2014, 110=2012
go
ALTER DATABASE [yourdatabasesname]  SET MULTI_USER
go
```

Answer (score 5):

There is also the [Upgrade Advisor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144256.aspx) which will help you identify anything in your DB which might cause problems when changing the compatibility level (basically a semi-automated way of doing what @steoleary has suggested which reduces the chances of you missing anything).

Comment: [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) has now replaced Upgrade Advisor, apparently.

Comment: Yeah this was for 2012 so not surprised they've changed the name and/or functionality. I've been out of the loop on upgrading DBs for quite some time as I rarely have much to do with DBs these days - not even sure what the latest version is!